# C++ password program, encountering problems with spaces

Tags: string, visual-c++, char, passwords, spaces

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream> // don't mind this 
    #include <ctime> //don't mind this either
    using namespace std;



int main() {

const string password = "hello"; //password
char word[100]; //if this were string and I put 2 words in my password it would output "invalid password" twice

do {
    cin >> word;
    cin.getline(word, 100);

    if (word == password) { //if word is equal to password, break and move on past the loop
        break;
    }
    cout << "Password invalid" << endl; //password not equal, it will move on to this and repeat until password is true
} while (true);
cout << "Password valid" << endl;



return 0;
}
```

I've been new to c++ programming for a couple months now, and I'm watching a very good course right now. In one of the tutorials he makes this password program that is present above. I've played with the program some and noticed that when I input 2 words like "example password" it would output "Invalid password" twice. I assume that is because it recognizes spaces as another input. I've made some changes so that now when I input 2 words or more it only outputs invalid password once. But now I'm facing another problem which I need help on. When I try to input the correct password, it doesn't work. What could be the answer to this mystery? Help would be appreciated and this could help me and others understand this more, and help avoid this problem in the future.

Comment: Since strings are not built-in data type in C++, So we use #include<string> use string class in c++ program . We declare string variable as string s; and take input as 'cin>>s' but this will only take string upto first white-space. In order to get whole string with white-spaces we use string input function getline as string s; getline(cin,s);

Comment: You can always use scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", string); to input strings with spaces.

Comment: Thank you a lot! This worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad that I already solved your problem, but let me elaborate on what I said earlier as it will be helpful for learning.

```
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", string );
```

Here the [^\n] is the scanset specifier for the scanf function, it means that the scanf function scans for characters from stdin untill it reaches a newline. This is basically a c function.

The parallel in cpp is getline(stream, char *) function, but almost all c code works in c++ hence you can use it.